# How to construct and access libcu++' <cuda/std/mdspan> on the host

Tags: c++, cuda, c++17, mdspan

libcu++ 2.1.0 includes an mdspan implementation for nvcc for c++14 and later.
I tried to implement the mdspan sample code from cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) with nvcc 12.0 and libcu++ 2.1.0

I noticed two problems.

First, I am unable to construct the `mdspan` in the same way as in the example.

> no instance of constructor "mdspan" matches the argument list
> argument types are: (int *, int, int)

Second, the access to `mdspan` via `operator[]` does not compile

> error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
> operand types are: cuda::std::__4::mdspan<int, cuda::std::__4::extents<std::size_t, 2UL, 3UL, 2UL>, cuda::std::__4::layout_right, cuda::std::__4::default_accessor> [ std::size_t ]

**1. How does one specify an extent in the constructor which is not known at compile-time?**

**2. How to access the data of `mdspan`?**

Below is my code which does not compile with `nvcc -Ilibcudacxx-2.1.0/include/ -std=c++17 main.cu -o main` .

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

#include <cuda/std/mdspan>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
 
    //error: no instance of constructor "mdspan" matches the argument list. argument types are: (int *, int, int)
    //auto ms2 = cuda::std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 6); 
    //auto ms3 = cuda::std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 3, 2);

    //no compilation error with compile-time extents
    cuda::std::mdspan<int, cuda::std::extents<std::size_t, 2,6>> ms2(v.data()); 
    cuda::std::mdspan<int, cuda::std::extents<std::size_t, 2,3,2>> ms3(v.data()); 
 
    // write data using 2D view
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != ms2.extent(0); i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != ms2.extent(1); j++)
            //no operator "[]" matches these operands. operand types are: cuda::std::__4::mdspan<int, cuda::std::__4::extents<std::size_t, 2UL, 6UL>, cuda::std::__4::layout_right, cuda::std::__4::default_accessor<int>> [ std::size_t ]
        ms2[i, j] = i * 1000 + j;
 
    // read back using 3D view
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != ms3.extent(0); i++)
    {
        printf("slice @ i = %lu\n", i);
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != ms3.extent(1); j++)
        {
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k != ms3.extent(2); k++)
                printf("%d ",  ms3[i, j, k]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libcu++ implementation of `mdspan` is [based on](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/pull/299#issue-1333828326) the reference implementation by Kokkos which has some [caveats](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/124b860f458e5c06c9b96d7510dc35b7acdd642b/README.md#caveats) in the readme:

> This implementation is fully conforming with the version of `mdspan` voted into the C++23 draft standard in July 2022.
> When not in C++23 mode the implementation deviates from the proposal as follows:
>
> #### C++20
>
> - implements `operator()` not `operator[]`
>
>   - note you can control which operator is available with defining `MDSPAN_USE_BRACKET_OPERATOR=[0,1]` and `MDSPAN_USE_PAREN_OPERATOR=[0,1]` irrespective of whether multi dimensional subscript support is detected.
>
> #### C++17
>
> - mdspan has a default constructor even in cases where it shouldn't (i.e. all static extents, and default constructible mapping/accessor)
> - the conditional explicit markup is missing, making certain constructors implicit
>
>   - most notably you can implicitly convert from dynamic extent to static extent, which you can't in C++20 mode
> - there is a constraint on `layout_left::mapping::stride()`, `layout_right::mapping::stride()` and `layout_stride::mapping::stride()` that `extents_type::rank() > 0` is `true`, which is not implemented in C++17 or C++14.
>
> #### C++14
>
> - deduction guides don't exist
> - submdspan (P2630) is not available - an earlier variant of submdspan is available up to release 0.5 in C++14 mode
> - benchmarks are not available (they need submdspan)

The reason for the reference implementation using `operator()` instead of `operator[]` (see section "C++20" above) is that `operator[]` **with multiple arguments** is a [C++23 feature](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf) so it can't be ported to earlier C++ versions. Therefore one needs:

```cpp
        ms2(i, j) = i * 1000 + j;
```

and

```cpp
                printf("%d ",  ms3(i, j, k));
```

instead.

The constructor that is used in the sample is implemented for C++17 and later (C++14 does not have the necessary CTAD*/deduction guides), or at least they have a [test](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/blob/9d2147e7cd3c646e9cf26712cce4fdacd996ed0b/.upstream-tests/test/std/containers/views/mdspan/mdspan.mdspan.cons/ctad_extents_pack.pass.cpp#L25) for it. CTAD might be [turned off for some (host-) compilers/versions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/blob/9d2147e7cd3c646e9cf26712cce4fdacd996ed0b/include/cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/__mdspan/config.h#L199-L206), but there is an [alternative way](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/blob/9d2147e7cd3c646e9cf26712cce4fdacd996ed0b/.upstream-tests/test/std/containers/views/mdspan/mdspan.mdspan.cons/extents.pass.cpp) of specifying dynamic extents without CTAD:

```cpp
int main() {
    ...
    using Ext2D = cuda::std::dextents<int, 2>;
    using Ext3D = cuda::std::dextents<int, 3>;
    auto ms2 = cuda::std::mdspan<int, Ext2D>(v.data(), Ext2D(2, 6));
    // This also works, i.e. CTAD doesn't seem to work,
    // but mdspan's variadic constructor does work in C++14 and C++17
    auto ms3 = cuda::std::mdspan<int, Ext3D>(v.data(), 2, 3, 2);
    ...
}
```

---

*CTAD: Class Template Argument Deduction